# Returning rows in PostgreSQL with a table called "user"

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `user`

I have some SQL that is `select User.* from User`

This fails because `User` is a reserved word however, I was under the impression that Postgresql didn't care about the case of the tables when executing the SQL so I assume there is a conflict because of the reserved word.

In the database the user table is lowercase so if I run this

`select * from user`

I get a result, although bizarrely I only get one column returned even though I said show all columns.

If I run `select * from "user"` I get all columns and also `SELECT "user".* FROM "user"` returns all columns.

Can someone explain what's going on please?

Thanks

(Using PostgreSQL 9.3)

Comment: OK so from the comments I see PG has its own user table. Why doesn't it work if I do SELECT * FROM "User" then?

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### `user` is a pseudo-function keyword

`user` is an alias for `current_user`, a built-in pseudo-function. It doesn't have the `()` of most zero-argument functions because that's how the SQL standards committee declared that it would be for `current_user`. I don't know why `user` follows that too, since I don't think the spec requires it.

### Functions can be used in FROM

Anyway, it's legal in PostgreSQL to specify a function in `from`, e.g.

```
regress=> SELECT * from clock_timestamp();
        clock_timestamp        
-------------------------------
 2014-09-03 17:00:59.191019+08
(1 row)
```

because a function that returns a single value can be used in a set-returning context too.

So when you run:

```
select * from user;
```

you're really doing:

```
select current_user;
```

### `"quoting"` escapes keywords

The reason it "works" if you write `"user"` instead is that *quoted identifiers are always user-identifiers, not keywords*. `user` is a keyword; `"user"` is a user-defined identifier that's a legal table name.

Confusing, no?

Usually `"tablename"` and `tablename` are the same (quoted-lower-case and unquoted-lower-case), *unless* `tablename` is a keyword.

This might make more sense if we pick a keyword that isn't a pseudo-function, so it's not legal syntax. Say:

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE "where" (id integer);
CREATE TABLE

regress=> CREATE TABLE where (id integer);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE where (id integer);
                     ^
```

### Quoting makes identifiers case-sensitive

Normally, PostgreSQL case-folds all identifiers to lower case. This is required by the SQL spec, though it actually requires *upper* case. So when you:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (id integer);
```

PostgreSQL actually creates a table named `mytable`. However, this case-folding is disabled if you `"double quote"` identifiers - again, per the SQL standard.

So the reason that:

```
select * from "User";
```

fails is that PostgreSQL, per the SQL standard, treats quoted identifiers as *case-sensitive*. So `"User"`, `"USER"` and `"user"` are all different things.

### How to avoid these problems?

Don't name your tables after keywords like type names, function names, etc. It's often legal, but it's rarely a good idea.

If you're going to use keyword names, you should *always* `"double quote"` them wherever they appear - and in fact make a habit of simply doing that for all your identifiers, all the time, and always using consistent case.

[There's a keyword list here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: And `select User.* from User` should not fail, right (despite the OP claims)?

Comment: @ypercube Sure it will. PostgreSQL case-folds `User` to `user`, which the parser sees as an alias for the `current_user` keyword. So you're writing `select current_user.* from current_user` which is nonsense. Now, `SELECT "user".* FROM "user"` is fine.

Comment: Oh, right. I was thinking it would behave as `select * from User` but apparently I need coffee. Thnx.

Comment: The real way to avoid these problems is always double quote your table names and columns, or just use an ORM.

Comment: Great answer, but put the solution `select * from "user";` right at the top, then follow with an explanation, because the solution already explains half of it: that there is some alias and "table-name" prevents the function call.